# All Java Files becomes red marked as error. but project build successfully

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gradle-plugin

I am using `android studio 1.0`. I am developing a small android application. When i was editing the code in one of my `java` file in android studio, power cut happened. 
After power came, i open the android studio and open my project, all files in the java folder marked as red indicationg error. 
but the projects build successfully. when i `sync with gradle`. 
it also done successfully. and perfectly runs in the device after launced the app in my phone.. but the red mark not disappear 
even i close the project and reopen. If i create new project also, the same things happen again.
     i can't understand what's happened. i also tried re install my `jdk 1.7`
Can anyone help me, how to fix this bug. please give exact solution. i don't like suggestions like to re install android studio

Comment: Try File->Invalidate caches and restart

Answer (score 0):

Try to Update to androidstudio  1.2

Comment: After update it will solve or not?. Are you face this problem before?

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

1. Close *Android Studio*
2. Go to `C:\Users\user\\.AndroidStudio2.3\system\caches` directory and delete all files.
3. Restart *Android Studio*

   Done.